# How can I clear the console in sicstus prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm developing a board game in prolog. It contemplates a type of game that allows a human to play against a bot. Since I'm using the same functions to validate the bot play it prints out the same auxiliar messages when the bot calculates all the possible moves.

My idea was to clear the board while it calculates all it's moves so it only outputs the final board in the end.

I'll leave the image to better explain myself.

[image: output I want to exclude]